# Unix commands on Azure csv files in blob

Tags: azure, csv, unix, sed

how to run sed command on some csv files i have in azure blob storage ?

I am using Azure copy activity to copy data from csv file to postgres, but my csv is a big 20 gb file and contains NULL character \x000 something.. which is not recognized by postgres Text data type. ADF copy activity cannot convert csv string columns to postgres abyte, so only option is to use Text. I thought of a workaround solution to run sed command on my csv to substitute null character with some other character like - . So I need to know how to run sed commands on azure csv files which are in blob storage. should i copy them first to a new vm which has linux, but also note that adf copy activity does not show an option to copy binary files from blob to some lunux vm

Answer (score 0):

You can't treat blobs as local files. You'll have to download them first, to local storage (local can be in your vm or anywhere else that your machine has access to). As for Data Factory: You definitely can copy content from a VM, as long as you create an appropriate file share (e.g. samba share), along with Integration Runtime, if the VM in question is locked down to a particular VNet.

Answer (score 0):

I simply added a resource i.e. a linux vm in ms azure subscription. copied files from azure blob to vm, ran sed command, copied files back to blob